# Write code that shows the difference in salaries between the top-paid employee and others per department

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Task:

> How much more the highest-paid employee gets compared to other teammates?
> Order the result by department and desc difference from max salary.

Input data:

```
val inputDf = Seq(
  (1, "Hunter Fields", "IT", 15),
  (2, "Leonard Lewis", "Support", 81),
  (3, "Jason Dawson", "Support", 90),
  (4, "Andre Grant", "Support", 25),
  (5, "Earl Walton", "IT", 40),
  (6, "Alan Hanson", "IT", 24),
  (7, "Clyde Matthews", "Support", 31),
  (8, "Josephine Leonard", "Support", 1),
  (9, "Owen Boone", "HR", 27),
  (10, "Max McBride", "IT", 75)
).toDF("id", "name", "department", "salary")
println("Input:")
inputDf.show(false)
```

My solution was:

```
 inputDf
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val windowSpec = Window
  .partitionBy($"department")
  .orderBy($"salary")
inputDf
  .withColumn("diff", first(col("salary")).over(windowSpec)-$"salary")
  .withColumn("diff", last(col("salary")).over(windowSpec)-$"salary")
```

Input:

```
+---+-----------------+----------+------+
|id |name             |department|salary|
+---+-----------------+----------+------+
|1  |Hunter Fields    |IT        |15    |
|2  |Leonard Lewis    |Support   |81    |
|3  |Jason Dawson     |Support   |90    |
|4  |Andre Grant      |Support   |25    |
|5  |Earl Walton      |IT        |40    |
|6  |Alan Hanson      |IT        |24    |
|7  |Clyde Matthews   |Support   |31    |
|8  |Josephine Leonard|Support   |1     |
|9  |Owen Boone       |HR        |27    |
|10 |Max McBride      |IT        |75    |
+---+-----------------+----------+------+
```

Expected:

```
+---+-----------------+----------+------+----+
|id |name             |department|salary|diff|
+---+-----------------+----------+------+----+
|9  |Owen Boone       |HR        |27    |0   |
|1  |Hunter Fields    |IT        |15    |60  |
|6  |Alan Hanson      |IT        |24    |51  |
|5  |Earl Walton      |IT        |40    |35  |
|10 |Max McBride      |IT        |75    |0   |
|8  |Josephine Leonard|Support   |1     |89  |
|4  |Andre Grant      |Support   |25    |65  |
|7  |Clyde Matthews   |Support   |31    |59  |
|2  |Leonard Lewis    |Support   |81    |9   |
|3  |Jason Dawson     |Support   |90    |0   |
+---+-----------------+----------+------+----+
```

But at the moment my actual result is not correct, because diff column is 0

Answer (score 1):

You should change window ordering to **descending**:

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy($"department").orderBy($"salary".desc)
```

and then:

```
scala> inputDf.withColumn("diff", first(col("salary")).over(windowSpec)-$"salary").show()
+---+-----------------+----------+------+----+
| id|             name|department|salary|diff|
+---+-----------------+----------+------+----+
|  9|       Owen Boone|        HR|    27|   0|
| 10|      Max McBride|        IT|    75|   0|
|  5|      Earl Walton|        IT|    40|  35|
|  6|      Alan Hanson|        IT|    24|  51|
|  1|    Hunter Fields|        IT|    15|  60|
|  3|     Jason Dawson|   Support|    90|   0|
|  2|    Leonard Lewis|   Support|    81|   9|
|  7|   Clyde Matthews|   Support|    31|  59|
|  4|      Andre Grant|   Support|    25|  65|
|  8|Josephine Leonard|   Support|     1|  89|
+---+-----------------+----------+------+----+
```